# jqGrid keeps on displaying "Loading"

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, asmx

I am using a asmx service to return data to display in jqGrid. I can see the json data is returned in complete callback. This is what json data in the complete callback look like `{"d":[{"__type":"HHSC.CTF.Business.BatchReceiptModel","BReceiptId"....`. I am not sure why it preceded by `d:` and also the type name for the data.
This is my jqGrid setup look like

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "../../WebServices/BatchReceiptsWebService.asmx/BatchReceiptsTable",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',   
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data, status) {

        },
        complete: function (xhr) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "BReceiptId",
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        records: function (obj) {
            return obj.d.length; 
        }
    },
    colNames: ['BReceiptId', 'ReceiptNumber', 'ReceiptAmount'],
    colModel: [
                    { name: 'BReceiptId', index: 'BReceiptIdnId', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'ReceiptNumber', index: 'ReceiptNumber', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'ReceiptAmount', index: 'ReceiptAmount', align: 'right', width: 100 }
                ],
    rowNum: 10,
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    viewrecords: true

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overwrite `success` and `error` callbacks of `jQuery.ajax` by usage the corresponding properties in `ajaxGridOptions`. If you examine [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L1948-L1986) of jqGrid you will see that jqGrid uses the callbackes. Inside `success` callbacks jqGrid process the server response and fill the grid, then it hide "Loading..." div. **By defining `success` and `error` callbacks inside `ajaxGridOptions` you beak Ajax processing used by jqGrid.**

Comment: Thank you so much Oleg and kmk. The grid displays the data now. My next task is to pass parameters to the service from the grid. Have had troubles with that, but I am going to try for sometime before asking for help :)

Comment: @GomtiMehta: You are welcome! jqGrid send some parameters to the server per default. If you need send additional data you can use `postData` parameter defined as object. I recommend you to define  properties of `postData` parameter as functions. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg, that's exactly what I did and it works like a charm :).

Comment: Answers from kmk and Oleg together worked for me, I dont know how to check both as asnwers :), would have been possible either answer alone :)

Answer (score 1):

Your jsonReader is looking a little jacked.  The 'd' character wraps the JSON return for ASMX service calls as of ASP.NET 3.5.  See here: http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

Try:

```
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            root: "d.rows", // or d dot whatever property name you use for the collection of data
            page: "d.page", // or d dot whatever property name you use for the current page 
            total: "d.total", // or d dot whatever property name you use for total pages
            records: "d.records", // or d dot whatever property name you use for total record count
            id: "BReceiptId",
        },
```

See here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data

I return an object that looks like this:

```
public class GridData<T>
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Records { get; set; }
    public List<T> Rows { get; set; }
    public object UserData { get; set; }
}
```

so my jsonReader is as follows (note the case sensitivity):

```
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            root: "d.Rows",
            page: "d.Page",
            total: "d.Total",
            records: "d.Records",
            userdata: "d.UserData",
            id: "Id"
        },
```

Comment: Hi kmk,Thanks for the quick response. I am returning a list from my webservice method like below    


        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<BatchReceiptModel> BatchReceiptsTable()
        {  


I do not have any Model to represent something like GridData as you have shown. I have class that only represents the type of items I am going display in the grid and list contains those. Is it required to create a type like "GridData?

Comment: Yes I'd recommend building an object that matches how you define the jsonReader.  And listen to Oleg below - your success, complete, and error handlers are being overrridden in the ajaxGridOptions prop.  Use the events to handle success and failure: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events